# Joomla simple registration form and recaptcha

Tags: php, forms, joomla

I'm stuck with Joomla registration form. 
There are lots of fields in this form so I want to remove all of them and leave only `email` field.

Instead of writing my own extension I decided to use an extension called `Simple Registration - Joomla!`. 
This extension uses native com_user model and overrides only one method in its model.

But the problem is that this module generates the form in its template. HTML code is inserted manually, but Joomla native extension uses fieldset to generate the form. Captcha is also included in this fieldset.

That's why Simple registration form does not have captcha validation. I've searched for examples where captcha is validated manually on this extension without success.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i decided to implement an old solution that had several depreciated methods.

```
    //get captcha result
    $post = $this->app->get('g-recaptcha-response');
    //load captcha plugun
    JPluginHelper::importPlugin('captcha');
    //get instance of the class that handles dispatching of events.
    $dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
    //check captcha results
    $res = $dispatcher->trigger('onCheckAnswer',$post['recaptcha_response']);
    if(!$res[0]){
        die('Invalid Captcha Code');
    }
```

Thats all, meh.